# Tableau: How can I display the filtered value passed via an Action while drilling down to another dashboard, in the filter field?

Tags: filter, action, tableau-api

I have several dashboards displaying employee survey data at different roll-up levels.

I'm using an Action to move from a summary of all employees, to detail on a single employee. So my filter is configured to pass the "Employee Name" to the next dashboard on click. So I can click on an employee from the list, and jump to the dashboard showing the summary of a single employee. This all works great.

The problem I'm trying to solve is that the drop down list filter for Employee Name on the Employee Detail dashboard doesn't adjust to the employee the action filters the list to, it still says (All). I.E. if I click on the record for John Doe, the jump and filter of the data works correctly, but the actual filter selector still says (All), rather than John Doe.

Is it possible to get the filter selection to update?

Comment: I can't think of a way to manipulate the filter that would work in this case - I'd suggest an alternative approach of a text box containing the name of the employee (taken from the action) and float this over the top of the filter on your second dashboard. Would this give the desired effect?

Comment: @BenP Rather than float it over the filter, I might try it as dynamic title and not worry about the filter, but that's a good thought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have created an Action filter, you can show that filter on a dashboard just like any other filters.
[image]

Comment: That's perfect, exactly what I needed! Thank you

Comment: As a note for anyone else reading this, you have to trigger the Action filter at least once before it will show up as an option in the filter menu.

Answer (score 0):

[Henry, because you have a filter on your dash, the action adds another filter but the only filter it's updated is the Action filter, in the image you could see the two filters updated only on the action filter... you could do so by using only dashboards filtering each others, because the dashboards always show the data in them, and you could make the action filters each other....](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C90oV.png)

[here is the dahsboard from the Regional Example Database of Tableau Desktop.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AORf1.png)

Comment: In this example you could see working the both filters: action filter and dashboard filter...